# Nested filtering of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have this constant `packages` that includes an array of `object_tags`

```
const packages = [{
   "id":"11",
   "object_tags":[
      {
         "id":"400",
         "tag":{
            "id":"30",
            "name":"Sample Tag"
         },
      }
   ],
},
{
   "id":"12",
   "object_tags":[
      {
         "id":"401",
         "tag":{
            "id":"31",
            "name":"Lost"
         },
      }
   ],
}]
```

and I want to filter the packages that only have the tag with the name `Lost`. So I tried `.filter()`

```
this.taggedOrders = packages.filter(item => item.object_tags[0].tag.name === 'Lost');
```

But I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

So I tried doing nested `.filter()`

```
this.taggedOrders = packages.filter(item => item.object_tags.filter(x => x.tag.name === 'Lost'));
```

but now it just returns the whole array, nothing filtered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I used `.some()`

```
this.taggedOrders = packages.filter(item => item.object_tags.some(x => x.tag.name === 'Lost'));
```

Answer (score -1):

you are almost there, with nested filter, you need to get to the first filter condition as well.. in this case you can use condition where the length > 0. ex:

```
this.taggedOrders = packages.filter(p => p.object_tags.filter(t => t.tag.name === 'Lost').length > 0);
```